# filter to not log logging entries of particular class

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-filter

I have a adonet appender and rolling file appender configure for my application. What i want is a filter on my adonetappender via which i can omit logging on particular class. That class has multiple level of devugging which I needed for my file appender. so i can't change the level and have to omit via filter.
My logging config is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <log4net>
       <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
        <file value="..\\Logs\\Logfile.txt" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
        <rollingStyle value="Date" />
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
          <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
          <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
          <levelMax value="FATAL" />
        </filter>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} %10p %-5property{_App} %-5property{_Node} [%2t] %5c{1}.%M - %m%n" />
        </layout>
      </appender>   
      <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
        <immediateFlush value="true" />
        <bufferSize value="0" />
        <connectionType value="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection, MySql.Data" />
        <connectionString value="data source=localhost;initial catalog=logging_db;User ID=root;Password=" />
        <commandText value="INSERT INTO system_log(appname, action, level)
                            VALUES(@appname, @action,@level);" />
        <parameter>
          <parameterName value="appname" />
          <dbType value="String" />
          <size value="32" />
          <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="My Web Service" />
          </layout>
        </parameter>
        <parameter>
          <parameterName value="action" />
          <dbType value="String" />
          <size value="150" />
          <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%c{1}" />
          </layout>
        </parameter>
        <parameter>
          <parameterName value="level" />
          <dbType value="String" />
          <size value="10" />
          <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%p" />
          </layout>
        </parameter>   
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
          <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
          <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
          <levelMax value="FATAL" />
        </filter>
      </appender>
      <root>
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />       
        <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
      </root>    
    </log4net>
```

My class name is MyNameSpace.Business.ConditionCompare
And in my class log4net object is declared as

```
private static readonly log4net.ILog Logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show your file appender in the config, but what you need to do is define a logger which overrides the appenders defined in root by specifying [`additivity="false"`](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger.Additivity.html): this allows the logger to choose which appenders to use. As you say you want to stop logging to the database altogether, you can tell the logger just to use the file appender:

Edit: add this just under the `root` element:

```
<logger name="MyNameSpace.Business.ConditionCompare" additivity="false">
   <level value="ALL" />
   <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
</logger>
```

Comment: I have edited my log4net config which shows how it actual looks. Can you please let me know where i should place this logger entry in my configuration?

Comment: Have change root element to 
<root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
    <logger name="MyNameSpace.Business.ConditionCompare" additivity="false">
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </logger>
  </root>
But it didn't work

Comment: remember i want to rollingfileappender do logging while adonetappender to skip logging for any logging in particular class  "MyNameSpace.Business.ConditionCompare"

Comment: @KamranShahid that is exactly what this does.

Comment: Ok will change my config and re-verify again. What i have seen is that there are entries in the logfile as well as my db for log entries of ConditionCompare class. After changing the config i do reset IIS to make sure that changes get effect. But will see again what's the problem

Comment: But you want entries in the file, just not the DB? You will want to make sure the logger being created by `System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType` has the exact name "MyNameSpace.Business.ConditionCompare"

Comment: Ok. I will log that out in and check is it same or different.
Thanks Stuart Dunkeld

Comment: Thx, worked for me. Just needed to add it behind the root like <root>...</root><logger>...</logger>. Not inside the root. Maybe you meant it like this but wasn't clear to me.

Comment: You’re right @mivra ‘under’ is ambiguous here. Glad it helped.